# Facebook Messenger Bot, can someone tell me how i catch the answer of a something i asked

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-messenger

So i working on my Facebook Messenger Bot.
I want to know ho can i catch a answer for a question like

> Bot: Enter your E-mail
>
> User: *enters e-mail*
>
> Bot: adress was added

My code looks like the sample app from [Facebook](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples)

```
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {

  var data = req.body;

  // Make sure this is a page subscription
  if (data.object == 'page') {
    // Iterate over each entry
    // There may be multiple if batched
    data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry) {
      var pageID = pageEntry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = pageEntry.time;

      // Iterate over each messaging event
      pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function(messagingEvent) {
        if (messagingEvent.optin) {
          receivedAuthentication(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.message) {
          receivedMessage(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.delivery) {
          receivedDeliveryConfirmation(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.postback) {
          receivedPostback(messagingEvent);
        } else {
          console.log("Webhook received unknown messagingEvent: ", messagingEvent);
        }
      });
    });

    // Assume all went well.
    //
    // You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds, to let us know you've 
    // successfully received the callback. Otherwise, the request will time out.
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag for their ID that the E-Mail prompt was sent, and then after they respond check to see if it's an E-mail, and if so, then save it and echo it back to them.

Answer (score 0):

If the bot is based on question/answer, what I normally do to handle response tracking is treat the bot like a finite state automata. Assign every "state" your bot can be in to some unique state identifier, and use said state identifier to determine what the user is replying to. You could also store callbacks instead of state ids, but high level this will behave the same way.

---

#### For Example:

First define a finite automata. In this case, lets assume it's:

```
0 --> 1 --> 2
```

Where 0 means new user, 1 means waiting for email response, 2 means user successfully completed registration.

1. User messages bot
2. We check our database and see it's a new user. We assume
   state==0.
3. Because state is 0, we ignore what was sent and prompt for email
4. Change state to 1 to denote the email was prompted.
5. User replies with email.
6. We check database and see state==1. We use the "1" routine to do fancy stuff to verify the email and store it.
7. Change state to 2 to denote the email was received and the program has ended.

---

#### Note:

- If the conversation id for the platform you're targeting is reset
  after a certain amount of inactivity (or if you just want the bot to
  mimic real conversations), store the time of each user's last
  interaction and purge all inactive conversations well after the
  conversation has been terminated.